# firstname lastname for additional authors in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I am still struggling with the de gruyter citation style. I know that I can produce one from scratch with `tex makebst`, but I have one that is almost working and I had to make a lot of funny changes, which I had to redo on the automatically created file.

The editors require me to have

> Meier, Max and Klaus Meier 2009  My first paper ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{SM.bib}
  @article{a,
    author={Max Meier and Klaus Meier},
    title={My first paper},
    journal={Journal of Googelology},
    volume=3123,
    number=1,
    pages={3--45},
    year=2009}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{degruyter-hsk} 
\bibliography{SM}

\end{document}
```

I know it is format.names, but how do I do it?

De Gruyter `.bst` is here: [degruyter-hsk.bst](http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/transfer/degruyter-hsk.bst)

Comment: How do the editors want pieces with three or more authors displayed in the bibliography?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another patch:

```
--- degruyter-hsk.bst.old   2013-07-05 11:04:03.000000000 +0200
+++ degruyter-hsk.bst   2013-08-10 12:16:40.000000000 +0200
@@ -396,7 +396,11 @@
   numnames 'namesleft :=
     { namesleft #0 > }
     { s nameptr
-      "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ 't :=
+      nameptr #1 >
+      { "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ }
+      { "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ }
+      if$
+      't :=
       nameptr #1 >
         {
           namesleft #1 >
```

Maybe you should learn the bibtex language and [tame the beast](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/), or switch to biblatex...